# Writing a program to count process memory pages in xv6

Tags: memory, system-calls, xv6

I'm trying to write a system call that returns the number of memory pages the current process is using but I have no idea where to start and which variables I should look at.
I saw two variables sz and pgdir in proc.h. But I don't know what each of them represents exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`proc.c`](https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/eeb7b415dbcb12cc362d0783e41c3d1f44066b17/proc.c), you have all you want to understand the memory management:

```
// Grow current process's memory by n bytes.
// Return 0 on success, -1 on failure.
int
growproc(int n)
{
  uint sz;
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();
  sz = curproc->sz;
    if((sz = allocuvm(curproc->pgdir, sz, sz + n)) == 0)
      return -1;
  curproc->sz = sz;
  switchuvm(curproc);
  return 0;
}
```

`growproc` is used to increase the process memory by `n` bytes. This function is used by the `sbrk` syscall, itself called by `malloc`.

From this, we assert that `sz` from `struct proc {` is actually the process memory size.

Reading `allocuvm` from `vm.c`, you can see two macros:

- `PGROUNDUP(size)` which transform a memory size to a memory size that is rounded to next page size,
- `PGSIZE` which is the page size.

So, the number of pages actually used by a process is **`(PGROUNDUP(proc)->sz)/PGSIZE`.**